# Using different page layouts in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-router

How can one achive to use different page layouts in angluar? E.g use a main-layout with topbar, side nav, main content area as default and a simpler layout for something like a login page?

I have achieved something similar by using child routes:

```js
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'demo', component: DemoComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```js
// app.component.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```js
// layout.component.html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>...</nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

Is there a cleaner way? I am not sure if child routes are intended to be used this way.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, but for me, it was for module-level

- One for the User module
- One for the Authentication module
- One for the Seach module ...

Here is what we did:

- Module level base component

  - Default route to this component
  - Contain `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
  - All the other components render in it

Hope it will give you an idea to proceed